# How can I make this C++ code to obtain passwords more efficient?

Tags: c++

The comments in the code kind of explain it. Backspace characters only move cursor back and don't erase output so I need to overwrite them with `' '` to delete them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const string PASSWORD = "PASSWORD";
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
string userkey = "";
char c;
int keystrokes = 0;


cout<<"Enter passkey: ";
while(true){
    if(_kbhit()){
        c=_getche();
        if(c=='\r'){//check if user hit enter, _getche() records enter as \r
            cout<<'\n';
            break;
        }   
        else if(c =='\b'){//check if user typed backslash, overwrite character there
            cout<<' ';
            if(keystrokes==1){ //makes sure userkey is cleared
                userkey = "";
                keystrokes--;
                cout<<'\b';
            }
            else if(keystrokes!=0){
                userkey = userkey.substr(0,userkey.length()-1);//cuts out last char of userkey
                keystrokes--;
                cout<<'\b';
            }
        }
        else if (c!='\b'){
            cout<<"\b*";//replaces enter char with'*'
            keystrokes++;
            userkey+=c;
        }
    }
}
//cout<<userkey;
if (userkey!=PASSWORD)
    return 0;
```

Comment: Do you understand that a hardcoded password gives very little security? Anyone can simply open the executable in Notepad and _see_ the password, as it will be a part of the binary.

Comment: I don't see where you defined those functions `_kbhit()` and `_getche()`, since you don't present them here, and don't have any includes for them.  But note that identifiers beginning with `_` are *reserved for the implementation*, so you should be using more portable names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding your program's efficiency, remember that premature optimisation is the root of all evil. Looking at your program, I can tell that your program will be IO bound - meaning that the computer will spend longer waiting for the user to input the data than actually executing your program. Moreover, functions like `std::cout` which deal with output, include inevitable slow system calls, which will be far costly in time than your algorithm. So performance should not be a concern here ! :)

The only thing I would say about your program efficiency is `const string PASSWORD = "PASSWORD";` which will use unnecessary copying and heap allocation. It is better to preserve the original type of the string like so:

`const auto PASSWORD = "PASSWORD";`  (Here `auto` (assuming c++11) deduces the type for you, but the real type of the string is `const char*` if you want to know)

**CODE REVIEW**

These are the style/ readability points I would make on your code.

- Use proper indentation (this might due to copy pasting on codereview so I don't blame you for that)
- Do not use `using namespace std` - this will lead to naming collisions and all sort of horrible errors. Better to use the `std::` every-time instead.
- You might consider to put the variable `PASSWORD` inside `main` as a `static const` variable, this will limit the visibility of `PASSWORD`.
- Use a better variable name than `c`.
- If your program gets bigger, consider wrapping your algorithm inside a function, this might help to make the `main` function a bit neater.

That's all! Well done, I would say generally this is very well written, readable c++ code.

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to C++ and this was very encouraging. Thanks for all of the suggestions, I'll change the variable name and definitely move this into a function, it's part of an encryption/decryption program. Would you say that using a break statement here is a good idea, or is there a better way to write the loop?

Comment: I think the break is fine. An alternative would be to do something like do... while (c !=  '\r') , but personally I prefer the break.